# How to prevent window to be clickable/do actions on it in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a javafx application and at a certain point I show a Popup this way:

```
public static void newWind(String fxml) throws IOException{

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("ABC");
            Scene newscene = new Scene(root1);
            newscene.getRoot().setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Arial'");
            stage.setScene(newscene);
            stage.show();

    }
```

The thing is that I want that the user can't click or do anything in the background non-popup window until he completes the operation in the popup. I want, basically, to "freeze" the old background window...

Comment: What you are looking for is a **modal dialog**, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html

Comment: Or just use https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initModality(javafx.stage.Modality)

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for answer, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: @James_D thanks to you too, but I am new to javafx and I don't know how to implement it

Comment: `stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);`

Comment: @JoopEggen Since the model stage doesn't have an owner, I think the OP will need `APPLICATION_MODAL`.

Comment: *"I don't know how to implement it"*. I linked the documentation. Just call the method I referenced.